# Split Buffer by seperator

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I split Buffer to array by seperator like

```
const array = split(buffer, '=')
```

In Go I can do like that

```
import "bytes"

parts := bytes.Split(buffer, []byte("="))
```

How can I implement same function in Nodejs?

Comment: Is your buffer an array of strings?

Comment: Are we talking nodeJs Buffer type, if so you could make a simple split function using `indexOf` and `slice`

Comment: @FarazShaikh yes

Comment: @Keith I'm not sure about that. Can you give me some example?

Comment: I'll see if I can knock up a simple example.  Give us a tick..

Comment: @Akashii A nodejs `Buffer` is not an array of strings.

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure about that. When buffer.toString() it return string

Comment: @Akashii [So?](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) That doesn't make it an array of strings. Lots of things have a string-returning `.toString()` method…

Comment: @Bergi you're right. My buffer display like Buffer(304){0:12,1:23,..}

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, you might be best using strings, as that has a split function,.

But if you do want to keep things as buffers instead of strings, Using slice and indexOf, you can create a simple split function,..

eg.

```
function splitBuffer(b, splitWith) {
    const ret = [];
    let s = 0;
    let i = b.indexOf(splitWith, s);
    while (i >= 0) {
        if (i >= 0) {
            ret.push(b.slice(s, i));
        }
        s = i + 1;
        i = b.indexOf(splitWith, s);
    }
    ret.push(b.slice(s));
    return ret;
}

//test
const b = Buffer.from('one=two=three');
console.log(splitBuffer(b, '='))
//result = [ <Buffer 6f 6e 65>, <Buffer 74 77 6f>,
//<Buffer 74 68 72 65 65> ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no built in way, at least that I am aware of. Try this

```
function splitBufToArr(buf, splitStr) {
    let start = 0;
    let bufArr = [];
    let isfound = true;
    while (isfound) {
        const idx = buf.indexOf(splitStr, start);
        if (idx === -1) {
            isfound = false;
            if (bufArr.length > 0)
                bufArr.push(buf.slice(idx));
            break;
        }
        const chunk = buf.slice(start, idx);
        start = idx + 1;
        bufArr.push(chunk);
    }
    return bufArr;
}

const buf = Buffer.from('1,5,8,9');
console.log(splitBufToArr(buf, ','));
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example below, we use library [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops), to process `Buffer` as an iterable:

```
import {pipe, split} from 'iter-ops';

const i = pipe(
    buffer,
    split(value => value === 0x3D) // 0x3D = code for '='
);

console.log([...i]); //=> split chunks of buffer
```

You can find more examples [here](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops/wiki/Split).